Ver todas las bases de datos conectadas a mi servidor sql en C#
Buenas estoy tratando de obtener el nombre de todas las BD que tengo conectadas en mi servidor sql, pero tengo una duda.
¿Como podría obtener solo las que tengo creadas en la carpeta databases excepto las que están en system databases?

No las que están en la capeta que esta marcada en rojo, las demás.
Uso este script
SELECT name FROM sys.databases

Pero me da todos los nombres, y no es lo que necesito.

Puedes valerte del campo is_distributor de la vista sys.databases, y siempre debes excluir los nombres master, model, msdb y tempdb.
De acuerdo a esta respuesta en SO en inglés, el propio Microsoft lo hace de esa menera.
La consulta sería algo como:
select name 
  from master.sys.databases 
 where name not in ('master','model','msdb','tempdb') 
   and is_distributor = 0 
 order by name;


Puedes evitar usar los nombres y solo usar los id que siempre serán del 1 al 4.

rayos, mejor no pudo funcionar, gracias bro
